Implementing Microsoft SSO with passport-azure-ad and without msal
I want to implement SSO sign up/sign in for Microsoft Azure AD B2C in NodeJS however, I want to create the user using Graph API. I'm using passport-azure-ad strategy. The process has to be custom because based on the user's info, a QR code is to be generated. So I just need the user object and the token.
I have passport strategy like this:
    ssoOptions = {
      identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.TENANT_ID}/${this.VERSION}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      clientID: this.TENANT_ID,
      clientSecret: this.TENANT_SECRET,
      redirectUrl: this.TENANT_REDIRECT_URL,
      validateIssuer: true,
      isB2C: true,
      loggingLevel: 'warn',
      responseMode: 'form_post',
      responseType: 'code id_token',
      passReqToCallback: true,
      scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
    }

    passport.use('oidc-strategy', new OIDCStrategy(ssoOptions, (req: any, iss: any, profile: any, accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, done: any) => {
      try {
      const userProfile = {
        oid: profile.oid,
        displayName: profile.displayName,
        email: profile._json.preferred_username,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken
      }
      return done(null, userProfile)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('ERROR', error);
      return done (error);
    }
    }))
  }

And I have this route in my route.ts: but it gives me 401: Unauthorized
    api.get('/ssoSignUp/authenticate', passport.authenticate('oidc-strategy', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
        res.json(req.user);
      });

And in my Azure AD B2C App Manifest, I have this:
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",


When testing the OAuth2 process in Postman, I see the Microsoft SSO Screen and when I enter my creds it says:

AADSTS50020: User account 'xyz@abc.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'AppName' and cannot access the application '123123'(AppName) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account


I also want to see both SignIn and SignUp in the SSO screen, right now I only see SignIn and get that above error.

My Postman options look like this:
Auth URL
https://login.microsoftonline.com/AppName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Access Token URL
https://login.microsoftonline.com/AppName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

Callback URL
https://localhost:3000/

ClientID: someID
ClientSecret: someSecret
scope: openid profile email
After some tinkering, I can now get the access_token from Postman:
My Auth URL is now this:
https://appName.b2clogin.com/appName.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_policy_name/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

But, I don't know what to do next with this. Basically, I want to create the user using graphAPI if it does not exist and update the azure id etc if it exists.
For my React App (just to test), these are my msalConfigs:
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '<clientID>',
        authority: `https://<tentantName>.b2clogin.com/<tentantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>/v2.0/`,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
        knownAuthorities: ['<tentantName>.b2clogin.com'],
    },
};

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read'],
};



Can you paste the parameters you passed in postman?

I've updated the question with the postman params

Thanks. I made a little edit update. I can now get the token with that route for Auth and /token for access token route. But kinda confused on next steps (controller, service etc)

The error you are facing is because you are passing invalid Auth URL and Access Token URL.
To resolve the error, you need to pass valid Auth URL and Access Token URL like below:
Auth URL : https://infrab2c.b2clogin.com/infrab2c.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL : https://infrab2c.b2clogin.com/infrab2c.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/token
Created an Azure AD B2C application:

Generate the token:
Auth URL : https://TenantName.b2clogin.com/TenantName.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Token URL: https://TenantName.b2clogin.com/TenantName.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/token

Callback URL: Redirect URL

Client ID: xxx

Client Secret: xxx

Scope: openid profile email



Note that: Only the ID token will be generated, to generate access token in Azure AD B2C you need to pass scope which is meant for the application.
Refer this SO Thread: Scope User.Read.All not works for azure b2c for more in detail for calling Microsoft Graph API

To create users you have to create Entra ID application in B2C tenant and use https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token and call the Microsoft Graph API as Azure AD B2C supports only offline_access and openid Microsoft Graph delegated API permissions.

Using Postman, I can get the OAuth2 token. However, when I try to authenticate it says Unauthorized. Can't figure out why. I am using the same credentials etc.
I've updated my passport strategy options (which I am using to get token from Postman too) and specified the route I am using to test

Do you get access token?

Yes, I get the access token from it. Using the same parameters as the ones in my passport strategy. But I can't authenticate with that route

You can't get access token using scope as Microsoft Graph in Azure B2C it's ID token

And using ID token you cannot create user

I did some research and it seems my approach was off target. I just need to make an SSO process that lets Microsoft authenticate and then, I create a user with that info in my database.

So what is the update now?

I'm creating a simple react app to test this. I've set the redirect URI to http://localhost:3000 (for my react app) and when I press the button that is supposed to let me redirect, it says:
AADB2C90068: The provided application with ID is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again.


This question might be getting a bit too long and a bit off from what I had originally posted. I think I should make a new question with the more updated information

This answer was useful and relevant to the original question, thank you. I've created a new question as well

Sure will check that
